# What to use instead of getWebContentsId() in newer versions of Electron

Tags: electron

Hi,
I had a project which used previous versions on electron.
In those versions we had a WebviewTag interface which was exported in electron and we can use it inside of our app.

But in newer versions, this interface is not exported and we have to use BrowserView class.

In WebviewTag there was a function getWebContentsId() which gives us the Id of the web contents of WebviewTag.

I would like to know what to use in BrowserView instead of that function.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [`BrowserView`'s documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-view#viewwebcontents-experimental), it exposes its `webContents` as a property. Thus, you can access the `webContent`'s ID by using `bv.webContents.id`, where `bv` is your `BrowserView` variable.

Also, [Electron's documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api) is a good resource for this kind of question.